# Sybase ASE looping over two tables for data calculation

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-ase

I'm not well versed with SQL and wondering how to do this in a Syabse - ASE stored procedure. Would appreciate any guidance on this.

I have table-1 (t1) and table-2 (t2) that I need to loop over for calculations like (t1.c4+t2.c3)*2+(t1.c5+t2.c4)*5.

**Steps:**

1. Get all the rows from table-1 whose datetime column value is between a user given datetime range
2. For each row from table-1 get row(s) from table-2 where the datetime value from table-1 row falls between start datetime and end datetime column values in table-2
3. If only 1 row matched from table-2, take the values from table-1 row and table-2 row and do calculations and do step-7
4. If more than 1 row matched, find the row from table-2 whose start datetime is an exact match with the datetime from table-1 row
5. If no exact match found, flag error in table-1 row and proceed with the next row from table-1
6. If only one row match found, do the calculations and do step-7
7. Insert the calculation result into the current row of table-1
8. Go to step-2; until no more rows left in table-1

What is the optimal approach to do this ? Should I use cursor's Or temporary tables ?

```
T1
------------------------------------------------
C1   C2    C3       C4                  C5   C6
------------------------------------------------
ABC  10   15        2019-03-01 00:30
XYZ  12   13        2019-03-01 01:00  
DEF  5    7         2019-03-01 02:00  
IJK  17   3         2019-03-02 01:00  

T2
------------------------------------------------
C1   C2    C3       C4                    C5
------------------------------------------------
LMN  1     5        2019-03-01 00:30   2019-03-02 00:00
OPQ  2     3        2019-03-01 01:00   2019-03-01 01:30
STU  4     2        2019-03-01 01:30   2019-03-01 03:00
KJF  3     1        2019-03-01 02:30   2019-03-01 03:00
```

User input: 2019-03-01 00:00 to 2019-03-01 00:30   (ABC & LMN Rows match)
Expected out:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C1   C2    C3       C4                  C5             C6
--------------------------------------------------------------
ABC  10   15        2019-03-01 00:30    (10*1)+(15*5)
XYZ  12   13        2019-03-01 01:00  
DEF  5    7         2019-03-01 02:00  
IJK  17   3         2019-03-02 01:00
```

User input: 2019-03-01 01:00 to 2019-03-01 01:30   (XYZ & OPQ Rows match)
Expected out:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C1   C2    C3       C4                  C5             C6
--------------------------------------------------------------
ABC  10   15        2019-03-01 00:30    
XYZ  12   13        2019-03-01 01:00    (12*2)+(13*3)
DEF  5    7         2019-03-01 02:00  
IJK  17   3         2019-03-02 01:00
```

User input: 2019-03-01 23:59 TO 2019-03-02 01:00 (IJK row & No matching rows in t2)
Expected output:

```
----------------------------------------------------
C1   C2    C3       C4                  C5     C6
----------------------------------------------------
ABC  10   15        2019-03-01 00:30
XYZ  12   13        2019-03-01 01:00  
DEF  5    7         2019-03-01 02:00  
IJK  17   3         2019-03-02 01:00         No matching row
```

User input: 2019-03-01 01:30 TO 2019-03-01 02:30 (DEF row)
Expected output:
Though DEF falls in STU & KJF date range start dates i.e. C4 col of either rows match with DEF datetime exactly

```
----------------------------------------------------
C1   C2    C3       C4                  C5     C6
----------------------------------------------------
ABC  10   15        2019-03-01 00:30
XYZ  12   13        2019-03-01 01:00  
DEF  5    7         2019-03-01 02:00          No unique match
IJK  17   3         2019-03-02 01:00
```

Comment: you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added expected outputs. Sorry for long question.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sybase ASE

Comment: If I correctly understood your question. First create a temp table from the results of "1.". Then iterate with cursor over it.
Note: It's important not to iterate over the same table you are actually inserting in.